Added memory to Supermicro server but manufacturer/part number not showing as expected
I have a 12-year-old Supermicro server that I just added memory to upgrade from 16 GB to 32 GB system memory.
[root@ares ~]# dmidecode --type 1
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Supermicro
    Product Name: X9SCI/X9SCA
    Version: 0123456789

I obtained 2 additional 8 GB DIMM's with the same specifications as the originally installed ones (Samsung M391B1G73BH0-CH9) off ebay that were advertised as used and working.
Functionally, all is well.  The system recognizes 32 GB total, and an mprime CPU/memory torture test passed.
When I delve deeper into the system info, though, the new DIMM's don't report specifications exactly as I expect.
Here is the system data before the memory upgrade:
[root@ares ~]# dmidecode --type memory
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: 0x000A
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: 0x000C
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_1A
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 128 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_2A
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 85C981DC
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M391B1G73BH0-CH9  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1333 MT/s

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: 0x0013
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_1B
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 128 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_2B
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 85C9820E
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M391B1G73BH0-CH9  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1333 MT/s

And now after the upgrade:
[root@ares ~]# dmidecode --type memory
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: 0x000A
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: 0x0011
    Total Width: 128 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_1A
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 85C981DC
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M391B1G73BH0-CH9  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1333 MT/s

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 128 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_2A
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 85C9820E
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M391B1G73BH0-CH9  
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1333 MT/s

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: 0x0014
    Total Width: 8 bits
    Data Width: 8 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_1B
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 0000
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1333 MT/s

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 8 bits
    Data Width: 8 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_2B
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 0000
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1333 MT/s

I'm seeing zeros for serial number and manufacturer, and "[Empty]" for part number on the new DIMM's.  I didn't expect that.  I thought I'd see "Samsung" for manufacturer, and new serial numbers that differed from the original DIMM's.



As seen in the pictures, the additional DIMM's have the same manufacturer and part number on the label.  The original memory was in the blue slots, and the new memory added to the black slots.  (Pictures represent pre- and post-upgrade.)
I also notice that the data width (8 bits) from the dmidecode data isn't what I expected.
Did I get fake memory, or is this an expected behavior?

“Did I get fake memory, or is this an expected behavior?” - Take the original memory out. Install the new memory in its place. Is the identification of the new memory the unchanged? Only you can really tell us if the memory is legitimate. We don’t have it in front of us. Memory identification is 100% code, so a legitimate module could be installed, but if the memory was never tested against the code to read the information could be being misinterpreted. Update dmidecode to the current release and try again

Why was one run with dmidecode 3.3 and the other with dmidecode 3.5?

Ramhound, I noticed the difference in dmidecode versions, as well.  The "before" one was done on May 10th, the "after" on June 1st.  In the interim time, there was a RHEL 8 update applied (8.9 --> 8.10), so I'm assuming that's the difference there.

Swapping the positions (new memory in blue spots) is a good idea as a test.  It's a bit of a challenge to get the server out of the rack, though, so I likely won't be able to test this until I can afford some downtime.
